# SQL update saying successful but doesn't update table in database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-update

I'm having an issue with a SQL update query, it says successful but doesn't actually update the database record.

```
<?php

    require_once('auth.php');

    $host="localhost"; // Host name 
    $username="root"; // Mysql username
    $password="sysadmin"; // Mysql password 
    $db_name="Elite"; // Database name 
    $tbl_name="Triage"; // Table name 

    mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
    mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

    $sql="UPDATE Triage SET directly='$directly', psychologically='$psychologically' WHERE Reference='$Reference'";
    $result=mysql_query($sql);
```

Comment: this is at the end also

if($result){
    echo "Successful";
    echo "<BR>";
    echo "<a href='list_records.php'>View result</a>";
    }
    else {
    echo "ERROR";
    }

    ?>

Comment: So where is `$Reference`?

Comment: `echo $sql` and try running it in PhpMyAdmin or your favorite MySQL tool.

Comment: There's a question here? All I see are unmatched/unreferenced variables.

Comment: reference is on the previouse page

Comment: $reference is on a form on the previous page and the above code runs off a action button

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql="UPDATE Triage SET directly='$directly', psychologically='$psychologically' WHERE Reference='$Reference'";
```

none of the variables used in that query have been defined in the code above. `$directly,$psychologically,$Reference`:  none have a value. Define values for those and that's it.

That `$Reference` is a must, even If others aren't.

Comment: sorry to be a plank, but could you give me an example? or how to set the value. cheers

Answer (score 0):

```
$refrence="1";
$sql="UPDATE Triage SET directly='$directly' AND psychologically='$psychologically' WHERE Reference='$Reference'";
```

replace $refrence with your MySQL ref

Answer (score 0):

Use this syntax

```
 $sql=  UPDATE Triage SET directly=?, psychologically=? WHERE Reference=?";
 $param->execute(array($directly,$psychologically,$Reference));
 $result=mysql_query($param);
```

Comment: i have tried this and this doesnt seem to work? do i need to customize it anywhere?